# Exception On Foreign Constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table StaffLevelMapping that has a foreign key column, which is a primary key another table AcademicLevel. It raises an exception that the Insert statement conflicted with a foreign key and it has its reference on the foreign key and the table in which it's a primary key. I know this usually happens if the value you are inserting does not exist in it's original table. But this does exist actually. I tried inserting it directly in SQL Server and it worked perfectly. But through my code it doesn't work. What surprises me the most is I used the same insert logic for the rest of my tables and I don't have problems save this one with this very table. Please I need a very quick help on this I have not slept in 2 days because of this error.

Here's my insert code below:

```
public static StaffLevelMapping AddStafflevel(int staffId, int levelId, bool isEnabled)
    {
        var context = ObjectContextHelper.CurrentObjectContext;
        var staffLevel = context.StaffLevelMappings.CreateObject();

        staffLevel.StaffID = staffId;
        staffLevel.ID = levelId;
        staffLevel.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
        context.StaffLevelMappings.AddObject(staffLevel);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return staffLevel;
    }
```

Many thanks in advance to that special person that can put me out of this misery.

Comment: Where are you setting the reference to AcademicLevel?  Is that the staffLevel.ID?  If not, that may be what is missing.

Comment: Show your table structure and error message, but like NYSystemsAnalyst says - where are you setting the AcademicLevel?  If it is levelID, should you be setting staffLevel.AcademicLevelID = levelID?

Comment: Oh My God! I did not believe the error was right there looking at me. I assigned the levelId variable to the primary key of the table instead of the LevelID which is the foreign key. You both are just awesome. Thank you very much guys, NYSystemsAnalyst and mcalex, you both just helped me in finishing my project of 8 months now. Very very many thanks guys. I really appreciate it.